# Как добавить релоки в секцию .reloc?

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

В исполняемом файле потребовалось использовать фрагмент кода в другом месте этого же .exe. Всё бы ничего, да только в фрагменте имеется функция, адрес которой находится в области перемещаемых данных, и с её копированием возникли проблемы. Пример функции: 68 *94003503*. (В листинге отладчик подчёркивает байты, которые могут быть изменены после каждого запуска файла).
Проблему можно решить добавлением соответствующего релока в секцию .reloc.
Как это конкретно осуществить? Если нет специнструмента, то хотя бы с помощью HEX-редактора.

Comment: Как вариант, вместо `call` можно делать `jmp` на `call` с готовым релоком.

Comment: И речь о формате PE?

Comment: jmp не проходит, т.к. есть возврат в  конце фрагмента.

Comment: Да, речь о формате РЕ.